# solving system of implicit functions - solution only satisfies one equation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to solve a system of two equations, one of them is implicit. Using Solve[], I got 2 solutions. However, one of the solutions is not a point for one of the equations, and graphically, the two equations do not cross at the point. I'm confused how mathematica calculated that solution, given it only satisfies of the equations. Here are the two equations, p and T are the only variables.

Equation 1:

```
p = \[Phi]/R + ((1 - \[Phi]) \[Phi] (1 - \[Lambda]) \[Beta])/(((W - 
        p T) R + \[Phi] T) R + \[Phi] (1 - \[Phi]) T)/(
 R (\[Lambda]/((W - 
        p T) R + \[Phi] T  ) + ((1 - \[Lambda]) \[Beta] R)/(((W - 
           p T) R + \[Phi] T) R + \[Phi] (1 - \[Phi]) T)))
```

and the second equation has constant product:

```
p = A/T
```

p and T are the only variables, the others are all parameters.

To solve the equations, I did:

```
Solve[p - \[Phi]/
    R - ((1 - \[Phi]) \[Phi] (1 - \[Lambda]) \[Beta])/(((W - 
           p T) R + \[Phi] T) R + \[Phi] (1 - \[Phi]) T)/(
    R (\[Lambda]/((W - 
           p T) R + \[Phi] T  ) + ((1 - \[Lambda]) \[Beta] R)/(((W - 
              p T) R + \[Phi] T) R + \[Phi] (1 - \[Phi]) T))) == 0 && 
  p == A/T , {p, T}]
```

and the solutions are:

```
{{p -> -0.0000199018, T -> -5.02466*10^6}, {p -> 0.319279, 
  T -> 313.206}}
```

However, when I substituted T = -5.02466*(10^6) into equation 1, I got
{p -> 0.325402} instead of {p -> -0.0000199018}

```
T = -5.02466*(10^6)

FindRoot[p - \[Phi]/
  R - ((1 - \[Phi]) \[Phi] (1 - \[Lambda]) \[Beta])/(((W - 
         p T) R + \[Phi] T) R + \[Phi] (1 - \[Phi]) T)/(
  R (\[Lambda]/((W - 
         p T) R + \[Phi] T  ) + ((1 - \[Lambda]) \[Beta] R)/(((W - 
            p T) R + \[Phi] T) R + \[Phi] (1 - \[Phi]) T))), {p, 0.2}]
```

output is {p -> 0.325402}

The parameter values are:

```
\[Beta] = 0.95
R = 1/\[Beta]
W = 1000000
A = 100
\[Phi] = 1/5
\[Lambda] = 0.1
```

Does anyone know how the solution {p -> -0.0000199018, T -> -5.02466*10^6} was derived? It's a point on equation 2 but not equation 1. In the graph below I plotted both equations. p is the y-axis, T is the x-axis. The blue line is p = A/T, why does it look squiggly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR** : Mathematica did do its job correctly with the initial `Solve`

I think there are many different things going on here. For one, `Solve` does throw a specific warning.

```
Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
```

If you substitute either of the answers provided by Mathematica they actually do satisfy both equations (to some level of numerical precision). Informed by the original warning when using `Solve`, I think this is due to a numerical precision issue.

Interestingly enough, if you flip the inverse equation and use `NSolve` this is no longer an issue.

```
exp1 = p - \[Phi]/
    R - ((1 - \[Phi]) \[Phi] (1 - \[Lambda]) \[Beta])/(((W - 
             p T) R + \[Phi] T) R + \[Phi] (1 - \[Phi]) T)/(R (\
\[Lambda]/((W - 
              p T) R + \[Phi] T) + ((1 - \[Lambda]) \[Beta] R)/(((W - 
                 p T) R + \[Phi] T) R + \[Phi] (1 - \[Phi]) T)));
```

```
NSolve[exp1 == 0 && p == A/T, {p, T}]
{{p -> 0., T -> -5.02466*10^6}, {p -> 0.319279, T -> 313.206}}
```

```
NSolve[{exp1 == 0, T == A/p}]
{{p -> 0.319279, T -> 313.206}}
```

Regarding the squiggly lines, I think again the artifact is from the `ContourPlot` that you are using. If you just use `Plot[A/T, {T, -10000, 10000},` this is non-existent.

So now the question becomes why is this not picked up in the `ContourPlot` that you generated. I think if you go far away (to the actual solution range), the plot is not properly generated. I could be wrong, but I think we are asking too much of `ContourPlot` at this point. To see why `{p -> 0., T -> -5.02466*10^6}` is a valid solution, I did the following.
I substituted for `p`, and just plotted the result versus `T`.

```
Plot[exp1 /. p -> 0, {T, -10^7, 10^7}]
```

And you can see, that this expression does indeed cross the x-axis at the very negative `T` value that was originally found.
[image: Plot of p->0 substituted expression vs. T]